# Print a receipt using Node.js to a dot matrix printer

Tags: node.js, printing

I would like to generate a receipt and print using a dot matrix printer. Currently i tried [pdf-to-printer](https://github.com/artiebits/pdf-to-printer) and it works but the the print has no clarity. How can i go about doing this properly. I want to print to a dot matrix printer from Node. Any pointers on how to go about doing this would be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue, it prints everything correctly but it doesn't has the same clarity as printing the pdf from any browser window for example. I haven't been able to find another way so far. What have you done?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to find a way for this. I switched to a laser printer.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I have no connection to pdf-to printer, However
It is using the print method I answer upon everyday.

I can be 100% certain why it is "fuzzy" and would have not recommended it for a Zebra Thermal or similar receipt usage, and you dont mention what type of Dot Matrix device you are printing on.

In essence it is using MuPDF rendering, which is designed for coloured screen output and is not designed for printing, unlike its sister product GhostScript which is not designed for viewing.

What it does behind the scenes is use SumatraPDF viewer (which I support) as a command line pdf to printer screen renderer then that sends images (not text or barcodes) to the printer driver.

Its very good at everyday inkjet colour printing but is not ideal for crisp laser or thermal as both often used for receipts where presentation on paper matters.

I will usually suggest first step is improve the windows print driver to one specifically designed for receipts such as Seagull for thermal printers.

Quality can be improved depending on a case by case study of the range of parameters, however you have not given a sample thus:-

The only possible answer is use a different method that targets printing such as the GhostScipt driver.

Comment: Epson LX-310 Dot Matrix Printer this is the printer i use.

Comment: I just used pdf because i found that library and thought it would work. There is no need to use PDF if its not needed. How do i go about using the native driver i am not sure how to do this some pointers would be really helpful